# cannot allocate memory - RSelenium and EC2

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, selenium, memory, rselenium

I am trying to implement a ***Selenium*** test to perform automated actions on a website (looping through pages). I am using ***R*** and ***RSelenium*** package as well as a ***PostgreSQL*** database using DBI package. All this using ***EC2 AWS*** server.

My problem is that after a few minutes that the script was launched, my ***RStudio*** session freezes (as well as my ***Linux*** session) and I can see a message like *"**cannot allocate memory**"*.
So this is clearly a memory issue without a doubt, and by doing `top` I could see that my ***Selenium*** docker was using most of the resources.

But my question is how can I reduce the amount of memory used by the ***Selenium*** test?

Comment: What instance type are you currently using? Can you use an instance type with more memory?

Comment: I use a t2.micro (memory size: 1024 Mio). I would like to understand what is driving that memory up before upgrading to another instance

Comment: I believe that selenium in a baseline configuration requires more than one gig of memory. You may be on an underpowered instance type to start with. No sense trying to tune tests or anything else if that is the case.

Comment: yes, will try on t2.medium then. Thx Rodrigo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO there is no practical way for a test to use less memory than the memory required by the given test. You can try to simplify the given test by breaking it up into 2  or more tests. Check for memory leaks, as suggested in another answer.

It would be much easier to use the next largest instance type with more memory, and shut down the instance when not in use to save money, if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget `drive.close()` in your code, if you don't close your driver, you will have a lot instance of Chrome.